# Deserialize Generic<T>

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api2, deserialization

I working on consistent response from web API. I am wrapping the desired object/entity in the `ApiResponsDTO` sent via API controller action method

```
public IHttpActionResult Validate([FromBody] PortalLoginDTO logindDTO)
{
    IHttpActionResult response = null;
    ApiResponseDTO<AppUserDTO> responseData = null;

    var user = _userservice.GetUserByName(logindDTO.Username);
    responseData = new ApiResponseDTO<AppUserDTO>(user, 200);
    response = new ApiResponseActionResult<ApiResponseDTO<AppUserDTO>>(responseData, 200);

    return response;
}
```

Response Class in API

```
public class ApiResponseDTO<T>
{
    private T _value;

    [DataMember]
    public string Version { private set { } get { return "1.2.3"; ; } }

    [DataMember]
    public double StatusCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public T Result { private set { } get { return _value; } }
    public ApiResponseDTO()
    {
        ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
    }
    public ApiResponseDTO(T value, double statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        _value = value;
        ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

In result field of the above class I want to send another requested object/class

requested class

```
[DataContract]
public partial class AppUserDTO
{
    public AppUserDTO()
    {

    }
    [DataMember]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Nullable<int> TitleId { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PasswordEncoded { get; set; }

}
```

On client MVC application I am using javascriptserializer

```
var responsedatda = serializer.Deserialize<ApiResponseDTO<AppUserDTO>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

I am getting the `ApiResponseDTO` but the requested class is not being serialized as seen in the image [Response in client side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHYy9.png)

what is the reason that I am not getting the nested `UserDTO` in API Response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The serializer needs to be able to set the underlying value of result but your code...

```
public T Result { private set { } get { return _value; } }
```

...does not allow for that as the serializer creates the class using the default constructor.

You need to update the `Result`  property...

```
public T Result { 
    get { return _value; } 
    set { _value = value; } 
}
```

OR you could refactor the class...

```
public class ApiResponseDTO<T> {

    [DataMember]
    public string Version { get { return "1.2.3"; } }

    [DataMember]
    public double StatusCode { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public List<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public T Result { get; set; }

    public ApiResponseDTO()
    {
        ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
    }

    public ApiResponseDTO(T value, double statusCode)
    {
        StatusCode = (int)statusCode;
        Result = value;
        ErrorMessages = new List<string>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nice article about readonly generic properties serialization:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/darrylru/2011/05/04/datacontract-serialization-with-generics-read-only-properties/